# CSS - Deixar uma distância (height) mínima entre dois elementos 'fixed'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preciso deixar uma distância mínima entre dois elementos de posição fixa (o topo e o rodapé). O problema ocorre quando aplica `zoom-in` na página, os dois elementos praticamente se encontram, sendo que o objetivo é deixar visível o conteúdo central da página.

Código CSS do menu fixo (topo):

```
div#menu {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:53px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Código CSS do rodapé fixo:

```
table#rodape {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer em CSS? Qual solução pode ser aplicada e se vou ter que recorrer ao uso de jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que existe diversas maneiras para resolver esse problema, realizei alguns teste aqui com o seu código. Testando e usando media queries ajudou a resolver o problema.

A questão é que você precisa de achar o breakpoint do comportamento indesejado, configura-lo na media query para que o Layout se adapte durante o Zoom-in.

```
   @media screen and (max-width: /*seu breakpoint*/){
        div#menu {
            /*sua adaptação*/
        }
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado. Um Abraço

Comment: Fiz as adaptações aqui. Obrigado! :-)